# How do I get the unique maxium or greatest (version ID) value to each (Record ID) with row data in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server I am joining 2 tables and need a way to get the maximum or greatest (version Number) value for each (Record ID) that exists in the table including it's row data selected.

My query is returning the data as follows but returns ALL record id's and versions, I need this to return only the max version number value and all row data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    MAX(a.VERSION_NUM), MAX(a.RECORD_ID), 
    b.PERSON, b.STATUS,  
    CAST(a.SUMMARY_DATA AS NVARCHAR(4000)) 
FROM 
    TABLE1 a, TABLE2 b 
WHERE 
    a.RECORD_ID = b.RECORD_ID 
    AND a.RECORD_ID not NULL 
    AND a.SUMMARY_DATA is not NULL 
GROUP BY 
    a.VERSION_NUM, a.RECORD_ID, b.PERSON, b.STATUS,
    CAST(a.SUMMARY_DATA AS NVARCHAR(4000)) 
ORDER BY 
    MAX(a.VERSION_NUM), MAX(a.RECORD_ID) DESC
```

This query returns duplicate Record ID's with its version number and row data:

```
VersionNum   Record ID           Person    Status    Summary Data
     5       000000000000418     John      Open      "specific Summary data ...
     4       000000000000418     Jane      Closed    "specific Summary data ..." 
     3       000000000000418     Sam       Closed:   "specific Summary data ..."  
     4       000000000000229     Joe       Pending   "specific Summary data ..." 
     3       000000000000229     Betty     Closed    "specific Summary data ..."
     2       000000000000229     David     Closed    "specific Summary data ..." 
     7       000000000000318     Karen     Closed    "specific Summary data ..."
     6       000000000000318     Sam       Pending   "specific Summary data ..."
     5       000000000000318     Betty     Closed    "specific Summary data ..."
     4       000000000000318     David     Closed    "specific Summary data ..."
```

I instead need this to return only the max (version number value) with it's adjacent (ID) and remainder of all it's selected row data :

i.e.

```
VersionNUM   Record ID         Person   Status     Summary Data 
    5        000000000000418   John     Open       "specific Summary data ..." 
    4        000000000000229   Joe      Pending    "specific Summary data ..."
    7        000000000000318   Karen    Closed     "specific Summary data ..."
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I applied and tried this but got an error - need help on the correct syntax to return these fields

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
   (SELECT 
        dt.VERSION, dt.Job_Doc_Set_Request_ID, dt.SUBMITTER,st.STATUS, dt.SUMMARY,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dt.Job_Doc_Set_Request_ID ORDER BY dt.VERSION DESC) rn 
    FROM 
        RICPM_JD_JobDocDetails dt, RICPM_JD_JobDocSet st) q 
WHERE  
    rn = 1 
    AND dt.Job_DOC_Set_Request_ID NOT LIKE '%DELETED'
    AND st.STATUS = 2 
    AND dt.SUMMARY NOT LIKE 'Obsolete%' 
    AND dt.Job_Doc_Set_Request_ID = st.REQUEST_ID
```

Error:

> java.sql.SQLException: The multi-part identifier "dt.Job_DOC_Set_Request_ID" could not be bound.
>           at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372) 
>           at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY recordId ORDER BY versionNum DESC) rn
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt response Quassnoi - i''ll try this

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use `outer apply`.  I have to guess a bit on what the actual query is, but I think:

```
SELECT b.*, a.*
FROM TABLE2 b OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 a.*
      FROM TABLE1 a 
      WHERE a.RECORD_ID = b.RECORD_ID AND
            a.RECORD_ID not NULL AND
            a.SUMMARY_DATA is not NULL 
      ORDER BY a.version_num desc
     ) a;
```